# Hide signup in amplify react application

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm working on an application built with amplify and react.
I have an auth module.

I want basically to have only one user, I don't want to let peoples create accounts.

My question is how to hide the sign up option ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hideSignUp` [property](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#sign-in):

```
<AmplifyAuthenticator>
  <AmplifySignIn slot="sign-in" hideSignUp></AmplifySignIn>
</AmplifyAuthenticator>
```

Comment: I tried to add that but it does not seems to work, it does nothing. No errors, it's like the code is not interpreted.

Comment: Did you check the version? Because this is a recent change as you can see here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/6098

Comment: never mind my last message, it works. I have to replace this export default  withAuthenticator(App, {
  includeGreetings: true,
  signUpConfig: {
    hiddenDefaults: ['phone_number']
  }
}) with a export default App;

Answer (score 2):

In `App.css`, or whatever appropriate style sheet, put

```
.amplify-tabs {
  display: none;
}
```

but make absolutely sure that it is imported after `@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css`.

I don't use style sheets, preferring inline styling, but this solution was so elegant I am making an exception!

https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization#additional-css-styling

Comment: This is a gem. Thank You!